# Omega ROM 4.4 bootloader/modem problems

Tags: rom-flashing, 4.4-kitkat, troubleshooting

Hi I was wondering if anyone else has had problems with this ROM update

[OMEGA ROM for Samsung Galaxy S4 I9505](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2253528)

I have followed the steps to flash the boot loader (completed successfully).
Flashed the model (failed) but once I booted into the ROM all was fine apart from I can't make any calls or receive calls. Or more specifically it will dial the call but the screen goes black like its froze/locked up. Has anyone seen this or a similar issue before that they may be able to help me with?

Comment: Have you tried asking the question in that thread? Usually, somebody should be able to help you in XDA, unless all they tell you is to BACKREAD the posts.

Answer (score 1):

Before you flash a modem, try another dialer app, just in case it is at fault. Check if 3g/LTE/WiFi are working at all. Chances are that it is the modem that is causing the issue but it is easier to install an app or two before flashing basebands.

On the Samsung Galaxy S4 International LTE model: GT-I9505 you cannot flash a Modem through recovery. You must use `Odin` to do this.

[Complete list of Modems for GT-I9505 and I9500 is here.](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/ref-galaxy-s4-i9500-i9505-gsm-non-hlos-modems-collection-odin-cwm-twrp.2192025/)

It is with noting that sometimes the first flash fails, and can even read as "Success" in Odin. Untick reboot and try it twice, then reboot the device.

You man need to try a couple of modems, but try initially to flash the one relative to your ROM (in your case `XXUFNAD`). However, the baseband (modem) can be different depending on your region/carrier/settings/ROM so a little trial and error is required. You may be using a 4.2 modem for example and this probably won't work. Most 4.3 and 4.4 modems will work fine in KitKat.

Edit:  [This is the recommended modem with the NEW bootloader](https://dfiles.eu/files/x2qckd8gi). This modem is `XXUEMJ5` version. Try this first. Then experiment with others.

Flash it in Odin as below, HOWEVER, do it separetely without the [bootloader](/questions/tagged/bootloader) option.

[image]
<sub>(source: [omega-roms.net](http://www.omega-roms.net/Photos/xda/odin_s4_i9505_XXUFNAD.jpg))</sub>